# Google analytics - Goal convesions showing up in "verify" but not in the goal view

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

Im trying to setup some goal tracking in google analytics on a new website.

The goals were not working, because i missed the trailing `/` from the URL. Ive now added the `/` and when i try to verify the goal it shows it was achieved a few times. See 1st screenshot below.

But when i go to view the goal in google analytics i get 0 goal conversions for the same period. See 2nd screenshot below. Any idea why ?

[image: goal verify in setup]

[image: goal view screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goals aren't applied retroactively, which is somewhat misleading from the ability of "Verify this goal" function. You would think that if Analytics could spot where a goal completion would have occurred in the past week, then they should be able to add that data to the reports. But they don't.

Completions are only logged based on the current configuration of the goal from the moment you click Save.

So, if the goal was incorrect for whatever reason, then those those goal completions wouldn't have been logged, and adjusting the goal will only work for future completions.

Regarding existing data, you could cross-reference whatever data you need from the past week with views of that specific page on your website. Using secondary dimensions, custom reports, or even Data Studio, you could pull up any information you need to know about converting visitors.

And for future reference, the "Begins with" option for destination goals can be very useful, particularly with highly distinctive URLs such as you have here. Especially if you might have any URL parameters in there.